# Pandas: Why applying a function doesn't work?

Tags: pandas, pandas-apply

I'm learning Pandas and I stumbled upon an exercise that wants me to create a new column (called legal drinker) within a dataset of alcohol consumers and fill it up with values True / False: True if the consumer is older than 17, False if not.

I can't figure out why one version of the code works and the other one throws an error. Could you help me, please? :)

```
# Works just fine:
def majority(x):
    if x > 17:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df["legal_drinker"] = df["age"].apply(majority) # new col created

# Doesn't work:
def majority(x):
    if x["age"] > 17:
        return True
    else:
        return False

df["legal_drinker"] = df.apply(majority)
```

Comment: Don't use apply here, just do `df['age'] > 17`, which returns the boolean mask you want.  However, the reason *your* code doesn't work is because you should just replace `x['age']` with `x`.  You are passing each row to your function, and the integer values don't have an `age` item

Comment: You can use `df['legal_drinker'] = df['age'] > 17` for short.  But, `df.appy(func)` will run func on each column of the dataframe.  So, for columns that or not 'age' and error will occur.  Because 'age' is not present to use in that calling of func.

Comment: You need to include `axis=1`

Answer (score 0):

The second function explicitly checks the `['age']` column of the DataFrame x that you pass as an argument.
However, the `df.apply(majority)` function applies your majority function to every column of the `df` DataFrame. This means that the `x` passed in `majority(x)` will be a single column of your DataFrame.
Of course, a single column doesn't have a column `['age']` (or any other column), so the interpreter can't find it and throws an error.
A shorter way to achieve this, as stated in the above comments is:

```
df['legal_drinker'] = df['age'] > 17
```